# How to generate hours and populate in sql table for a period

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to create a table with columns having date,hour as a separate fields for a period of time say 10 years from 1st Jan 2010 to 1st Jan 2020.

I have created calendar table referring to url : 
[click here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

It generates only dates,day,week,month but not time.
I want to generate new column with the value as 0,...23 hours for every day.

Comment: I think it is better to make another table with 1..24 hours. Then include both tables (hours + date-only) in `WHERE` and will have all combinations.

Comment: perhaps if you explain why you want to do this you might get a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it an another easy way as follows

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT NUMBER FROM master.dbo.spt_values where TYPE='P' AND NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 2047
)
, YEARS AS(
SELECT NUMBER+2009 AS  Y FROM CTE WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 11
)
,MONTHS AS (
SELECT NUMBER AS M FROM CTE WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 12
)
,DAYSS AS(
    SELECT NUMBER AS D FROM CTE WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 31
)
,HRS AS (
    SELECT NUMBER AS H FROM CTE WHERE NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 24
)
SELECT * FROM YEARS Y
CROSS APPLY MONTHS M
CROSS APPLY (SELECT  D FROM DAYSS 
WHERE D<= DATEDIFF(DD,DATEFROMPARTS(Y.Y, M.M,01),DATEADD(MM,1, DATEFROMPARTS(Y.Y, M.M,01))))D
CROSS APPLY HRS H
ORDER BY Y.Y, M.M, D.D, H.H
```

**Sample Result:**

```
+------+---+----+----+
|  Y   | M | D  | H  |
+------+---+----+----+
| --   | - | -- | -- |
| 2020 | 2 | 29 | 21 |
| 2020 | 2 | 29 | 22 |
| 2020 | 2 | 29 | 23 |
| 2020 | 2 | 29 | 24 |
| 2020 | 3 |  1 |  1 |
| 2020 | 3 |  1 |  2 |
| 2020 | 3 |  1 |  3 |
| --   | --| -- | -- |
+------+---+----+----+
```

> Note: `DATEFROMPARTS` function will work only with SQL Server 2012 and
>   above. You can replace it by concatinating them and converting to date
>   field for lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

Either create another table that holds 24 rows for each hour of the day or use a derived table like so

```
SELECT
     H.[Hour]
    ,D.[Date] 
FROM
    dbo.DateDimension D
CROSS APPLY
(   --Derived table with 24 rows
    SELECT
        [Hour] = V.number
    FROM
        master..spt_values V
    WHERE
        V.type = 'P'
    AND
        V.number >= 1 AND V.number <= 24
) H
WHERE
    [D].[Date] = '2000-01-01'
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a time table as well as your Calendar table. How specific you get with your times is up to you (for example, mine has a value for every second in a day). Then, simple `JOIN` to too:

```
SELECT * --Yes, * is bad, but I don't know what the OP's Columns are.
         --The OP will need to replace the * with the appropriate columns
FROM CalendarTable CT
     JOIN TimeTable TT ON TT.[Minutes] = 0 AND TT.[Seconds] = 0
WHERE CT.DateValue >= '20100101'
  AND CT.DateValue < '20200102';
```

The filter means that only the Hour values would be returned.

Also, it's worth noting there is no hour `24` in a day. The hours are 0 - 23, not 1-24.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
--set start variables
declare @period_length_days     as int      = 21
declare @start_dt               as datetime = getdate()
declare @end_dt                 as datetime = dateadd(day,@period_length_days,getdate())

--declare table
declare @my_calender table (recid int identity(1,1), 
                            my_datetime     datetime, 
                            my_year         int, 
                            my_month        int, 
                            my_day          int, 
                            my_hour         int)
                            --of course you can add multiple more: iso_wk, minute, second etc etc

--fill table
declare @loop_dt as datetime = @start_dt
    
    --loop from start_dt to end_dt, by adding 1 hour each cycle, until loop_dt = end_dt
    while @loop_dt <> @end_dt 
    begin
    insert into @my_calender 
        select 
            @loop_dt
        ,   datepart(year,@loop_dt)
        ,   datepart(month,@loop_dt)
        ,   datepart(day,@loop_dt)
        ,   datepart(hour,@loop_dt)
        
        

    set @loop_dt = dateadd(hour,1,@loop_dt)

    end
    
    select * from @my_calender
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to *why* you would do it like this. Answers with little to no explanation of what the answer does and why it solves the problem aren't very useful in the sense that you can't tell whether or not it actually solves the problem at a glance.